# Is Casper implemented yet?

Tags: mining, proof-of-stake, proof-of-work

So as far as I understand, Proof-of-stake works by all nodes voting on what they think the correct next block should be and then recieving a small reward out of thin air if they guess correctly and a small penalty if they guess incorrectly. Thereby all nodes are incentivized to believe the same thing.

This then means that there is no useless incrementing-a-nonce-and-trying-to-hash-and-come-up-with-a-value-below-some-limit puzzle, which means it should greatly reduce the work of processing blocks and save miners a lot of cost, which in turn means they can offer a lower gas price.

*So what is "mining" in this context? Is it just running a load of transactions, putting a block together, and then convincing everyone else your candidate is the one they should vote for? Is there still a system where the miner of a new block gets a big payout as in bitcoin, or does everyone who votes for the right thing split the payout?*

*[Buterin wrote about all this nearly two years ago](https://blog.ethereum.org/2015/12/28/understanding-serenity-part-2-casper/). Has it made it in to the protocol yet?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Casper testnet is expected soon:

https://www.coindesk.com/ethereum-soon-launch-first-casper-testnet/